# Why are nearly all my NFS calls for syscltid and syscltidconf?

Tags: nfs

I manage an installation with 1 server running Ubuntu 12.04 and 60 Raspberry Pi microcontrollers running raspbian.  Each Pi mounts an NFS drive from the server to read new code and store logs.

We are experiencing serious network latency and the server's bytes in and out have increased dramatically (500 kB/s to 8 MB/s).

After doing an nfsstat, I noticed that nearly all of the calls are "setcltid" and "setcltidconf".  I cannot find a description of those calls anywhere (google, man nfs / nfsstat, here), but something tells me they shouldn't be 99.99999% of all calls.  Here's the nfsstat output:

```
Server rpc stats:
calls      badcalls   badclnt    badauth    xdrcall
79155136   0          0          0          0

Server nfs v3:
null         getattr      setattr      lookup       access       readlink
1       100% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0%
read         write        create       mkdir        symlink      mknod
0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0%
remove       rmdir        rename       link         readdir      readdirplus
0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0%
fsstat       fsinfo       pathconf     commit
0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0%

Server nfs v4:
null         compound
4         0% 79057350 99%

Server nfs v4 operations:
op0-unused   op1-unused   op2-future   access       close        commit
0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 14461     0% 27901     0% 0         0%
create       delegpurge   delegreturn  getattr      getfh        link
0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 93133     0% 36808     0% 0         0%
lock         lockt        locku        lookup       lookup_root  nverify
0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 2927      0% 0         0% 0         0%
open         openattr     open_conf    open_dgrd    putfh        putpubfh
66698     0% 0         0% 2586      0% 8         0% 128989    0% 0         0%
putrootfh    read         readdir      readlink     remove       rename
3998      0% 1810      0% 13        0% 92        0% 0         0% 0         0%
renew        restorefh    savefh       secinfo      setattr      setcltid
10299     0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 370       0% 39754648 49%
setcltidconf verify       write        rellockowner bc_ctl       bind_conn
39689677 49% 0         0% 7319      0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0%
exchange_id  create_ses   destroy_ses  free_stateid getdirdeleg  getdevinfo
0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0%
getdevlist   layoutcommit layoutget    layoutreturn secinfononam sequence
0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0%
set_ssv      test_stateid want_deleg   destroy_clid reclaim_comp
0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0% 0         0%

Client rpc stats:
calls      retrans    authrefrsh
0          0          0
```

If someone can offer any shred of advice it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What is your `clientaddr` setting on the clients? It sounds like the same symptoms as [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mountall/+bug/1037192/comments/21):

> With clientaddr=0.0.0.0, nfsstat -s showed rapidly incrementing 'setcltid' and 'setcltidconf' operations on the server, and high IO utilization on the root volume due to writing v4recovery information.